# Detect and print if no command line argument is provided

Tags: python

This is the program I have:

```
from sys import argv

script, arg1 = argv

def program(usr_input, arg1):
    if(usr_input == arg1):
        print "CLI argument and user input are identical"

    else:
        print "CLI argument and user input aren't identical"

if arg1 != "":
    usr_input = raw_input("enter something: ")
    program(usr_input, arg1)

else:
    print "You have not entered a CLI argument at all."
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, arg1 = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

How can I detect the lack of command line argument and throw an error/exception instead of receiving this error?

Comment: argv's just an array of args... so check how long it is.

Comment: Consider a minimal test-case: `a, b = ["oops"]` Why does this not work? How would it be fixed/avoided?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would recommend just checking the program args in the `__main__` location of your script, as an entry point to the entire application.

```
import sys
import os

def program(*args):
    # do whatever
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        arg1 = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        print "Usage: " + os.path.basename(__file__) + " <arg1>"
        sys.exit(1)

    # start the program
    program(arg1)
```

Comment: Thank you! I like this answer better. Was using `IndexError` instead of `ValueError` a personal choice or is there a significant reason?

Comment: Also, I think `program(arg1)` at the end of the code doesn't need indentation.

Comment: Yes IndexError is needed when you are indexing only one element (1 in this case) instead of unpacking a wrong number of args. You only had one arg so I used that approach. Also yes the indent is required. This is a python idiom for creating a script that can be both imported from another script or run as an executable. If you dont indent that last line it will run code if you ever import this.

Answer (score 3):

You can handle the exception:

```
In [6]: def program(argv):
    try:
        script, argv1 = argv
    except ValueError:
        print("value error handled")
   ...:         

In [7]: program(argv)
value error handled
```

Comment: What is this syntax: `In [6]`? or did you mean `in line 6` or something like that?

Comment: Its from the ipython interpreter and replaces >>>. It does read like in line.

Comment: Oh! I forgot about being able to write functions in python command line. ipython seems cool too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
script = argv[0]
try:
    arg1 = argv[1]
except:
    arg1 = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `try` statement there:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import sys

class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.error_string = value

    def __str__(self):
        return eval(repr(self.error_string))

try:
    script, arg1 = sys.argv

except ValueError:     
    raise MyError, "Not enough arguments"
```

Comment: Typically it is frowned upon to make custom exception subclasses that just pass and do nothing else. The standard library has an abundance of descriptive exceptions to raise. But other than that, I would vote this up for just being the simply approach in the global space. Try to parse args, and catch and print error and exit.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that `sys.argv` is a list you should check the length of the list to make sure it is what you wish it to be.  Your script with minor changes to check the length:

```
from sys import argv

def program(usr_input, arg1):
    if(usr_input == arg1):
        print "CLI argument and user input are identical"
    else:
        print "CLI argument and user input aren't identical"

if len(argv)== 2:
    arg1 = argv[1]
    usr_input = raw_input("enter something: ")
    program(usr_input, arg1)
else:
    print "You have not entered a CLI argument at all."
```