# Python: reading filename from command line argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am making a simple script that counts some values from a csv file generated from google forms.

The script is as follows:

```
import csv
import os.path

fileName=None

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        fileName=argv[1]
        isFile(fileName)
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print("You must provide a valid filename as parameter")
        raise

def isFile(fileName):
    if(not os.path.isfile(fileName)):
        raise ValueError("You must provide a valid filename as parameter")

print fileName


def readCsvAndCountPercentPerFormItemFromGoogleForms(fileName):
    times={}
    totalRows=0
    with open(fileName,'r') as csvfile:

        csvReader=csv.reader(csvfile);

        for row in csvreader:

            value=row[1]

            if(value in times.values()):
                times[value]+=1
            else:
                times[value]=1

            totalRows+=1

        return calculateDictionaryAsPercent(times,totalRows)

def calculateDictionaryAsPercent(times,totalRows):

    if(totalRows==0):
        raise ValueError("The file does not contain any rows")

    for key,val in times.items():
            times[key]=(val/totalRows)*100

    return times


finalTimes=readCsvAndCountPercentPerFormItemFromGoogleForms(fileName)

print finalTimes
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import csv
  File "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/python/csv.py", line 54, in <module>
    finalTimes=readCsvAndCountPercentPerFormItemFromGoogleForms(fileName)
  File "/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/python/csv.py", line 26, in readCsvAndCountPercentPerFormItemFromGoogleForms
    with open(fileName,'r') as csvfile:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

The problem is that for some reason the variable `fileName` does not change value in:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        fileName=argv[1]
        isFile(fileName)
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print("You must provide a valid filename as parameter")
        raise
```

The following piece of code was base ton the first answer found on [Detect and print if no command line argument is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14016742/detect-and-print-if-no-command-line-argument-is-provided)

So can you offer me a solution because I do not write python too often, therefore I did the following script in order to learn it better.

## Edit 1

The code has been reformated to this:

```
import csv
from sys import argv
import os.path


def isFile(fileName):
    if(not os.path.isfile(fileName)):
        raise ValueError("You must provide a valid filename as parameter")


def readCsvAndCountPercentPerFormItemFromGoogleForms(fileName):
    times={}
    totalRows=0
    with open(fileName,'r') as csvfile:

        csvReader=csv.reader(csvfile);

        for row in csvreader:

            value=row[1]

            if(value in times.values()):
                times[value]+=1
            else:
                times[value]=1

            totalRows+=1

        return calculateDictionaryAsPercent(times,totalRows)

def calculateDictionaryAsPercent(times,totalRows):

    if(totalRows==0):
        raise ValueError("The file does not contain any rows")

    for key,val in times.items():
            times[key]=(val/totalRows)*100

    return times


fileName=None

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        fileName=argv[1]
        print("Filename: ",fileName)
        isFile(fileName)
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print("You must provide a valid filename as parameter")
        raise

print("Filename: ",fileName)
finalTimes=readCsvAndCountPercentPerFormItemFromGoogleForms(fileName)

print finalTimes
```

Still the same error.

Comment: You have to `def isFile(fileName):` __before__ you try to call it.

Comment: It seems your file is named `csv.py`. You can't `import csv` in a file named `csv.py`; it'll simply import itself. Choose a different name for your file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end as mentioned the script should be this one:

```
import csv
from sys import argv
import os.path


def readCsvAndCountPercentPerFormItemFromGoogleForms(fileName):
    times={}
    totalRows=0
    with open(fileName,'r') as csvfile:

        csvReader=csv.reader(csvfile);

        for row in csvReader:

            value=row[1]

            if(value in times.values()):
                times[value]+=1
            else:
                times[value]=1

            totalRows+=1

        return calculateDictionaryAsPercent(times,totalRows)

def calculateDictionaryAsPercent(times,totalRows):

    if(totalRows==0):
        raise ValueError("The file does not contain any rows")

    for key,val in times.items():
            times[key]=(val/totalRows)*100

    return times


def isFile(fileName):
    if(not os.path.isfile(fileName)):
        raise ValueError("You must provide a valid filename as parameter")

fileName=None

if __name__=="__main__":
    try:
        fileName=argv[1]
        isFile(fileName)
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print("You must provide a valid filename as parameter")
        raise

finalTimes=readCsvAndCountPercentPerFormItemFromGoogleForms(fileName)

print finalTimes
```